# How to remap a keyboard key using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

How do I remap a key on the keyboard using Java so that I can give the key a new meaning?

Comment: Is this to use only in your program? Like in games (edit controlls). Or do you mean the whole system-keyboard layout?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux i'm looking for something to remap my pageup key to (ctrl + win + left) and pagedown to (crl + win + right)

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren: On OS X, search for Karabiner. For other platforms, I guess similar applications will exist.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, it's how to explicitly define behavior for a specific key. Here's how I do this to implement keyboard shortcuts -- hopefully it answers your question. In my example below, I believe you can change 'this' to be the specific component you wish to explicitly set the keyboard behavior on, overriding its default behavior. I usually do this in the context of a panel or frame.

```
private void addHotKey(KeyStroke keyStroke, String inputActionKey, Action listener) {
    ActionMap actionMap = this.getActionMap();
    InputMap inputMap = this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    inputMap.put(keyStroke, inputActionKey);
    actionMap.put(inputActionKey, listener);
}
```

The inputActionKey is just an arbitrary key string to use for mapping the action. An example of invoking this method to listen for the DEL key:

```
    KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0);
    Action listener = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // delete something...
        }
    };
    addHotKey(keyStroke, "MainWindowDEL", listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand the context of your question. But theoretically you could intercept all KeyEvents and then dispatch a different KeyEvent based on your criteria. [Global Event Dispatching](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/06/global-event-dispatching/) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score -1):

Capture key-events:

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(myListener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

Simulate key press:

```
java.awt.Robot.keyPress(myKeyCode);
```

Comment: and what will you do with that keypress once you capture it?

Comment: Get the typed key and remap it to your own. Isn't this what was asked for?