# Remap my keyboard keys (q = aaaa) (1 button = multiple definition)

Tags: java, keyboard, remap

Can anyone tell me how to remap my keyboard keys where if I press "q" my computer will generate/type "aaaa". This needs to work outside my Java application as well.

```
final int oldKey; 
final int newKey;

try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("jTextField1");
    oldKey=s.nextInt(16);
    System.out.println("<81><81><81><82>"); 
    newKey=s.nextInt(16);
}
Thread t;
t = new Thread() 
{
    public void run() {
        RemapKeys o = new RemapKeys();
        try {
            o.remapPassedKeys(oldKey,newKey);
        } catch(Exception exc) {
        }
    }
};
t.start();
```

Comment: I had tried multiple referencing including all the below link
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450383/how-to-remap-a-keyboard-key-using-java-swing)
[link](https://cooltrickshome.blogspot.com/2016/11/remap-your-keyboard-keys-and-mouse.html)
[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBVOXTgXX2U)
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YylKa3C_qQc)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Im using window

Comment: So the 2nd link you found should work.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: so i using java netbeans. Inside the netbeans program i type what the web had written under "Java Program". Afterwards I convert the file to .h using command prompt. Then I typed what the web written under .h and .cpp section, and save it. And I'm currently stuck where I not sure what to do with the file I save both .java .h and .cpp. I also have a problem where I not sure whether the coding I made is correct or not. I'm sorry for taking your time. I really tried a lot of ways and references over the past weeks. I really appreciate your help :D

Comment: *"And I'm currently stuck where I not sure what to do with the file I save both .java .h and .cpp."*  You compile them with a C++ compiler, then link them.  You probably need to read a tutorial on compiling and linking JNI libraries on Windows.

Comment: The other approach would be to identify the Windows command-line utility for changing key bindings, and use `Process,exec` to run it.

Comment: I still have difficulty on compile my file. [link](https://cooltrickshome.blogspot.com/2016/11/creating-your-personal-keylogger-from.html) I followed this tutorial where i uses command prompt to create .h and .cpp file and I uses dev-C++. Inside dev-C++ i paste what the this link had written [link](https://cooltrickshome.blogspot.com/2016/11/remap-your-keyboard-keys-and-mouse.html). After i paste it, the program not allowing me to compile it where it show few error. I did not change any coding that was provided by the website.

Comment: I dont mind sharing screen shot if you need it. Thanks a lot, I really really appreciate your help :D

Comment: 1) Please don't post screenshots.  Post the error messages as text.  2) I won't be able to help.  Others might be able to.